# Как закрашивать отдельные тайлы в тайлмэпах в unity2d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создаю игру на unity2d. В ней игрок при соприкосновение со стеной закрашивает её часть. Уровень создавал через Tilemap, собственно 1 тайл - это и есть часть стены. Проблема заключается в том, что при соприкосновение со стеной закрашивается вся стена, а не её часть.

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
    {
        collision.gameObject.GetComponent<TileMap>().color = new Color(0,0,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну да, `collision.gameObject.GetComponent<TileMap>().color` это и есть весь цвет стены.

Comment: Это понятно, а как только одну ячейку из всего тайлмапа закрасить?

Comment: Тайлмапы не использовал, не знаю.

Comment: Ладно, и на этом спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Уже не помню как именно реализовать, но вот тебе методы необходимые [WorldToCell](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GridLayout.WorldToCell.html) - получаешь конкретный тайл, а после с помощью [SetTile](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.SetTile.html) меняешь

Comment: хотя б какой-то минимальный пример явно бы не помешал.